# Displaying an object within an object in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this class

```
 export class Test {
    
    public id:string;
    public car : Car = {id:0,name:'Volvo'}
    
    }
```

How to display the car's name in html ?

This does not work

```
          <tr *ngFor="let test of tests;let i = index">
            <th scope="row">{{ i + 1 }}</th>
             <td>{{ test.id }}</td>
             <td>{{ test.car.name }}</td>
             <td>
            </td>
          </tr>
```

The tests array is properly filled.

Comment: you need to instantiate the test class

Comment: You declared Test class, but in the template you're looping through array of tests using ngFor, 
If you do have an array of tests in your component then your code will work other wise if you only have one class and you want to use its members in the template then you only need an instance of this class and no need for the "ngFor".

Comment: Hi Ali Jamal. I have an array of tests in my component with car object inside it in valid json format. I want to display the car name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate your class.

```
const test = new Test();

this.tests = [test];
```

Comment: Hi. It is instantiated already. tests : Test [] is filled and contains car object. I want to get that value on the html side within ngfor

Answer (score 0):

The web service returned values which had null car objects and this caused the error in angular.

```
         <td>{{ test.car.name }}</td>
```

works fine when ALL objects returned have this property. Even if there is a mixture of null, not null, it does not work.

Comment: You can fix this with [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)
{{ test.car?.name }}